# Get float number instead of integer after the conversion of day/time to months using Pandas library

Tags: python, pandas, math, statistics, data-science

I have DataFrame which looks like this -

```
  37 days 19:07:00
  69 days 02:32:00
  44 days 00:38:00
  14 days 07:30:00
  14 days 23:03:00
  41 days 16:41:00
```

I want to convert this time into months for which I am using this code -

```
df_new['difference'] = df_new['time'].dt.total_seconds().div(60).astype(int)
```

This is giving me results but for days less then 30 it is returning me 0 months so I want a decimal value of this column instead of absolute number. How can I do that? My ultimate goal is to find mean of this column.

My current output looks like column one and my desired output is in column 2.

```
Current 
1
2
2
5
0
0

Desired 
1
2
2
5
0.2
0.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change astype(int) to astype(float)

code:

```
df_new['difference'] = df_new['time'].dt.total_seconds().div(60).astype(float)
```

Comment: It worked. thank you. How can I limit decimals to 2 digits after decimal ?

Comment: Hey @bella try method round(). Code: round(df_new['difference'], 2). Which means that you want only 2 decimal numbers.

Comment: @Isabelle if my solution worked for you, please mark my answer with the green check symbol which you can find on the left side of the answer (it will be green after click). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`.astype(int)` will return an integer, based on what you need you should use `.astype(float)`

`.round(2)` will round off the values to 2 decimal places, but I'd advise to round-off to 2 decimals after you have gotten the average. Do note that pandas will only display up to 6 decimal places when the output is printed. However, rest assured that when you call the value, the accuracy which you have specified will be there.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=['a','b'])
>>> df['c'] = df['a'].div(7).astype(float)
>>> df['d'] = df['a'].div(7).astype(float).round(2)
>>> df['e'] = df['a'].div(7).astype(float).round(7)   # only 6 d.p. displayed
>>> df['f'] = df['a'].div(7).astype(float).round(10)  # only 6 d.p. displayed (uh-oh!)
```

But when you 'call' the values, you'll see the specified accuracy:

```
>>> df['d'][0]
0.1428571
>>> df['e'][0]
0.1428571429
```

Comment: It worked. thank you. How can I limit decimals to 2 digits after decimal ?

Comment: With reference to the link below, all you have to do is to add .round(2), but I'll suggest to average the values first before rounding. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is on way and using `np.where`

```
news=pd.to_timedelta(s).dt.total_seconds().div(30*60*60*24).round(1)
news=pd.Series(np.where(news>1.0,news.round(0),news.round(1))).astype(object)
news
Out[919]: 
0      1
1      2
2      2
3    0.5
4    0.5
5      1
dtype: object
```